# List one attribute for each row in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, form-for

I haven't found any answer for this, or even a similar question.

The point is to have list simmilar to one below **but** in `form_for/simple_form_for`:

```
= Ingredient.find_each do |ingredient|
    %ul
        %li= ingredient.name
```

So, all what I need is to have a list of all `ingredient.name` in checkboxes.

Is it possible? or am I missing something pretty obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form for `your model` can be defined like this:

```
= form_tag path_to_controller_mathod do
  %ul
    - Ingredient.find_each do |ingredient|
      %li
        %span= label_tag ingredient.name
        %span= check_box_tag "ingredients[]", ingredient.name
```

`ingredients` means that in controller `params` will contain `ingredients` attribute, an array which contains only selected values

Comment: Is it needed `find_each` without arguments?

Comment: Got following error undefined method `merge' for "asDAD":String
@Sebastian it doesn't need to be each but I'm pretty fresh and I don't know how to get one full column from table

Comment: You could use [`ActiveRecord#pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck).

Comment: Looks fine but have no idaea how to use it in this particular case

Comment: @MajQel I updated the answer to avoid the problem that you've described, please check

Comment: undefined method `ingredients'
@IgorDrozdov this Model doesn't have own controller, in application there is only one controller for Recipe model

Comment: if I use `check_box_tag` will I lose some fucntionality??
 Because as far as I can see it works with `%span= check_box_tag ingredient.name`

Comment: As long as it provides you an array of checked options into controller params, you won't lose functionality